Error Using the azure playfab API endpoint to get time
Initially, I was using the endpoint POST https://titleId.api.main.azureplayfab.com/Client/GetTime, and it was working fine as intended. However, for the past few days, I have been encountering an issue with the endpoint, receiving the error:
https://<playFabTitleId>.api.main.azureplayfab.com/Client/GetTime net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.
I have rechecked for the id I have been using in place of playFabTitleId and checked the documentation, there is mention of the above end point URL.
The code looks like below:
const response = await fetch(`https://${playFabTitleId}.api.main.azureplayfab.com/Client/GetTime`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-Authorization": sessionTicket
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({}) // empty payload for GetTime
});
const data = await response.json();

if (data.code === 200) {
    return new Date(data.data.Time).getTime();
} else {
    console.error("Error:", data.errorMessage);
}


Can anyone confirm if this is a valid endpoint, or is there any other issue?
